# The category view is repeated many times instead of once in django

Tags: python, django

I have a problem displaying a category view from a Kategorie class. The query shows me correctly the number of pages added to a category, but this action is repeated more than once. When I check the detailed view for the displayed categories in one loop, each of the displayed categories has the same address. This action is repeated for each category where the next loop displays a detail view for the next category and so on.
This mis my **views.py** for that method:

```
def widok_kategorii(request):
    kategorie = Kategorie.objects.all().order_by('glowna')
    return render(request, 'firmy/widok_kategorii.html', {'kategorie': kategorie})

    def index(request):
    wpisy_kat = Kategorie.objects.annotate(cnt_witryna=Count('witryna')).order_by('glowna')
    return render(request, 'firmy/index.html', {'wpisy_kat': wpisy_kat})
```

The **widok_kategorii.html**

```
{%  for kategoria in kategorie %}

{% for wpis in wpisy_kat %}
 <a href="{% url 'detale_kat' slug_kat=kategoria.slug_kat %}">{{ wpis }} </a> ({{ wpis.cnt_witryna }})  <br />
{% endfor %}

{%  endfor %}
```

And the part of **index.html** to display the widok_kategorii.html

```
<h3><center>Kategorie</center></h3>
        <center>{%include 'firmy/widok_kategorii.html'%} </center>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think, you need to remove external loop, replace your:

```
{%  for kategoria in kategorie %}

{% for wpis in wpisy_kat %}
 <a href="{% url 'detale_kat' slug_kat=kategoria.slug_kat %}">{{ wpis }} </a> ({{ wpis.cnt_witryna }})  <br />
{% endfor %}

{%  endfor %}
```

to

```
{% for wpis in wpisy_kat %}
 <a href="{% url 'detale_kat' slug_kat=wpis.slug_kat %}">{{ wpis }} </a> ({{ wpis.cnt_witryna }})  <br />
                                   <!-- ^^^^^ -->
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: when I do that the compiler bringing me back the error like : NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'detale_kat' with keyword arguments '{'slug_kat': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['kategoria/(?P<slug_kat>[\\w\\-_]+)/$']

Comment: try fixed in answer, replace `kategoria` to `wpis`

Comment: Great it is. It's working ! So maybe advantage the opportunity You can help me how to display around 60 categories what I have in for example 3 or 4 columns instead 1 ?

Comment: there are many way, simple it split your result on view, or you can write custom tags for the reason https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/